# Online demat account for stock market

Tags: stocks, india, financial-literacy

I am planning to open a stock market online account in India. My question is do I need to pay any extra charges on the days when I dont play stock market.

Comment: Why don't you check with your stock broker?

Answer (score 2):

As said in previous answer, bank account, demat account and a brokerage firm.

- Bank account

You will be having a bank  account.

- Demat account & Brokerage firm

The required documents are regulated across the players. You must spend some effort to decide the above two. Other things to consider are the annual charge and  commission. 
For first timers, go with the one provided by banks (viz Icici direct). Later on do compare others (sharekhan, karvy, ZeroDha).

Answer (score 1):

To trade in stocks you need 3 things

1. Your bank account
2. A demat account. These days there is no annual charges, but quarterly holding charges. Very nominal ...
3. A online trading account. These days there are no annual fees. Only fees when you trade. Typically in the range of 0.25 percentage of trade value.